# BST implementation in Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

This is my implementation of BST in Java.

```
public class BST {
    Node root;

    public BST(){
        root = null;
    }
//    public BST(int item){
//        root = new Node(item);
//    }

    private class Node{
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        public Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }
    }

    public void add(int item){

        add(item, root);
    }

    private  Node add(int item, Node p ){
        if(p == null){
            p = new Node(item);
        }
        else if(item < p.data) p.left = add(item, p.left);
        else if(item > p.data) p.right = add(item, p.right);
        return p;
    }
     public void inorder(){
          inorder(root);

     }
    private void inorder(Node p){
        if(p == null) return;
        inorder(p.left);
        System.out.print(p.data + " ");
        inorder(p.right);
    }
}
```

This is the calling code.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        //BST bst = new BST(13);
        BST bst = new BST();
        bst.add(12);
        bst.add(7);
        bst.add(3);
        bst.add(2);
        bst.add(19);
        bst.add(4);
        bst.add(17);
        bst.add(11);
        bst.inorder();
    }
}
```

The issue here is when I use the BST parameterized constructor, everything works as expected. But if I dont and use the default constructor, the root continues to remain `null` and nothing gets added. Can't seem to understand why this is happening. The debugger gives a `null pointer exception` inside the `add` helper call. But the way my `add` is defined if a null `root` is the caller, then there should be no exceptions at all. My question is why is the BST with default constructor not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct `add` method like this:

```
public void add(int item)
{
    root = add(item, root);
}
```

instead of this:

```
public void add(int item)
{
    add(item, root);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this method `private  Node add(int item, Node p )` you are returning `p` but then `public void add(int item)` doesn't store it. So basically whatever object you are returning, doesn't have a reference.

Change:

```
public void add(int item){

        add(item, root);
    }
```

to:

```
public void add(int item){
        if (root == null) 
            root = add(item, root);
        else 
            add(item, root);
    }
```